# How can I prevent base64 decoding in AWS EventBridge input transformer for avro encoded messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, avro, aws-event-bridge

I have an eventbridge pipe that is pulling messages from a self managed kafka topic which contains avro encoded messages. I want to use an enrichment aws lambda function to decode those payloads before sending them to an SQS queue. Whenever I use the input transformer the value is trying to get decoded inside the sample screen (see image).
How can I maintain the same base64 string in the output?

I've tried quoting the property in different ways but it always gets decoded. I'm expecting to pass the base64 encoded value as it is to the enrichment lambda.